# Snowflake - User Administration - Role to allow user to Set / Update RSA Key

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have a requirement where we have users who have to be allowed to set their RSA Key, so that it will remove the unwanted burden & lead time  on the ADMIN.

How do we create a Role (Access level to be provided) which can allow the user to set their own RSA_PUBLIC_KEY or RSA_PUBLIC_KEY_2

Comment: allowing users to set there own RSA keys seems wrong and dangerous. Now if you had a system the logged in with (SECURITYADMIN I assume is the required level) and thus users hit some internal infrastructure and get their daily/weekly token, and the new token is put into snowflake, that makes sense..

Comment: According to https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-overview.html `USERADMIN` should be the level you need..(for a automated system, but users should not have the ability to create/alter other users. is is the level required it seems to alter these settings as deduced from the https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-user.html#usage-notes which notes the things a normal user can set for themselves.)

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim, thanks for your insights, but I see this is very similar to Password, why it should be taken away from user.

Comment: Snowflake doesn't let a user change their own password via sql ether.